# How do I loop and compare 2 columns in 2 worksheets and reference increase or decrease?

Tags: excel, vba, loops, compare

I want to compare 2 columns from 2 different worksheets (The same column in each sheet), then compare if they have increased or decreased, then color the cell red or green to indicate if increased or decreased. However my formula doesn't work... 
I tried the columns on the same sheet using activecell, and activecell offset and it worked, but I cant seem to reference it in another sheet?
But is my (unworking) code...

```
Sub test3()
      Range("A1").Select
Do
  If ActiveWorkbook.worksheets(“Sheet1!”).Cell(ActiveCell) > ActiveWorkbook.worksheets(“Sheet2!”).Cell(“A1”) Then 
        ActiveCell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    ElseIf ActiveWorkbook.worksheets(“Sheet1!”).Cell(ActiveCell) < ActiveWorkbook.worksheets(“Sheet2!”).Cell(“A1”) Then 
        ActiveCell.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
    Else

    End If
         ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
End Sub
```

Comment: I think your issue is the second cell in the comparison is always "A1".

Comment: In addition to hard coded `A1` I would not loop the way your are doing it and you can simplify all those `ActiveWorkbook` and `ActiveCell` references. I've offered an alternative approach below

Answer (score 1):

Try this, just need to set column to whatever column index you need.

```
Dim row As Integer
Dim column As Integer

row = 1
column = 1

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1!").Cells.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)

Do While ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1!").Cells(row, column) <> ""

    If ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1!").Cells(row, column) <> ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2!").Cells(row, column) Then
        If ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1!").Cells(row, column) > ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2!").Cells(row, column) Then
            ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1!").Cells(row, column).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        Else
            ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1!").Cells(row, column).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
        End If
    End If
    row = row + 1
Loop
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to help! However there is an error saying runtime error 9 subscript out of range? Any ideas on that one?

Comment: I have no idea - how do I find out which line it relates to?

Comment: If you debug test3 it should highlight the line that's failing. The error is probably because it can't find the name of the sheet either "Sheet1!" or "Sheet2!", make sure the names in code match the names on the spreadsheet. (I did have to change your ” quotes to " in my VBA project for your sample to run...)

Comment: If I dubug by "step into" then "stepOver" it highlights the sub title, then row, then column, then first active workbook line - then the error pops up again....

Comment: Hard to say from that description, sorry. Perhaps you could post the code you've got now, and add a comment where the error occurs...

Answer (score 0):

This will work - just change the `colorRng` reference to suit your needs:

```
Sub ColorCode()
    Dim cl As Range, colorRng As Range

    Set colorRng = Worksheets(1).Range("A1:A10")

    For Each cl In colorRng
        If cl > Worksheets(2).Cells(cl.Row, cl.Column) Then
            cl.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        Else
            cl.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
        End If
    Next cl
End Sub
```